# What is the German word for “mind”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Is there a word in German to refer to *the mind? Gehirn* is *brain*, but that’s the meat inside the head, not the mind. In Spanish it is *mente*. Is there a German equivalent?

I have consulted my dictionary app and it gives me *Geist, Seele, Sinn, Verstand, Gedanke, Absicht, Ansicht, Gedanken,* and *Gemüt.* These seem to be related to the concept of *mind* as I understand it in English, but not quite the same. (i must admit that at my level I don’t get many of the nuances of these words).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is very usual that words of one language do not cover all meanings of a word in other language. You have to choose a word depending on your situation. 
And as Guy Deutscher wrote in one of his books

> **The Germans have no mind** (because they do not have a word which covers the meaning of english "*mind*" to 100%):
>
> - Verstand (he's got the mind of a four-year-old! - er hat den Verstand    eines Vierjährigen!)
> - Geist (a fine mind - ein großer Geist)
> - Seele    (frame of mind - seelische Verfassung)
> - Denkweise (to the Victorian    mind - nach viktorianischer Denkweise)
>
> **...und die Engländer haben keinen Geist**
>
> - mind (der menschliche Geist - the human mind)
> - wit (er sprühte vor    Geist - he was as witty as could be)
> - intellect (kleine Geister -    people of limited intellect)
> - spirit (der Geist der Zeit - the spirit    of the times)
> - brain (seinen Geist anstrengen - to use one's brain)

Source: Guy Deutscher's book "Du Jane, ich Goethe. Eine Geschichte der Sprache" or in "Im Spiegel der Sprache" ("The Unfolding of Language. The evolution of mankind's greatest invention" and "Through the Language Glass" respectively)

Comment: "Geist" is nearest to "spirit" in meaning, including the alternate meanings of "ghost" and "alcohol" :)

Comment: @rackandboneman This is a quotation so I can not change it :) (I formatted the text as quotation now)

Comment: Well they have a geist... the zeitgeist! :D

Comment: "mind" can also mean "Kopf", or "Sinn". Actually "mind" refers to anything sort of cognitively related, we don't have such a "general" word for that

Comment: "You're always on my mind"? Du bist immer in meinen Gedanken?

Answer (score 12):

## mind ≈ Geist & Verstand

Have a look at the wiki articles for each [*Geist*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geist) and [*mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind). By definition both words mean the same.

But we also have *Verstand*, which means *understanding* (noun). *Verstand* is related to *verstehen* which means *to understand*.

By definition we have:

> - Geist = Mind
> - Verstand = understanding (noun)
> - verstehen = to understand

Even tough *mind* and *Geist* are closer by **definition**, look at this example and see how similar *mind* and *Verstand* are in **practice**:

> - Have you lost your *mind*!? = Hast du deinen *Verstand* verloren!?
> - Use your *mind*, stupid! = Benutz' deinen *Verstand*, Dummkopf!
> - Boy, you have a sharp *mind*. = Junge, du hast einen scharfen *Verstand*.
> - You can train your *mind* = Du kannst deinen *Verstand* trainieren.
> - He's got the *mind* of a four-year-old! = Er hat den *Verstand* eines Vierjährigen!
> - She has a clear *mind* = Sie hat einen klaren *Verstand*.
> - My *mind* tells me... = Mein *Verstand* sagt mir…

In German you may use *Geist* and *Verstand* other than you would expect in English. Just replace *mind* with *understanding* and read the English sentences from the list again. That way you see it from a German native perspective. It may seem unusual, but the sentences still make sense. Both ways work. German just developed into using the other.

However, you don't always use *Verstand* for *mind* in *practice*, e.g.:

> What have you got on your mind?

doesn't translate to *Was hast du auf deinem Verstand?*. But this is somewhat easy to recognize, because if you do the swap again, it would read *What have you got on your understanding*, which doesn't sound good.

A direct translation to *What's on your mind?* could be something like this:

> - Was hast du im Sinn?
> - Was schwebt dir vor (im Geiste)?

## Geist ≈ mind & spirit

If you refer to *Geist* regarding the intellect and psyche of a person it is mostly the same as *mind* by definition. But *Geist* also translates into *spirit*. And there you have another mix-up between the two languages. In German you use *Geist* for both *mind* and *spirit*. For example:

> Das war der Geist der Epoche.

The preferred translation would be *"It was the spirit of that epoch."*.
But if you refer to *Geist* as *mind* you have: *"It was the mind of that epoch."*. The first sentence works fine. The second sounds strange, but it is not far from earth.

The word *Geist* has a broader meaning, it merges *mind* and *spirit*. It contains both. Its meaning is defined by the context it is placed in. From a German perspective you just put *Geist* in the sentence and leave it for the reader to decide if he wants to put the emphasis more on the *spirit* side or more on the *mind* side or take the mix of both. But in the end it's mostly context and common sense that define the meaning of *Geist*.

Here are some examples for when I would say *Geist* emphases on spirit rather than mind:

> - Das ist der Geist der Epoche.
> - Das passt zum heutigen Zeitgeist.
> - Sie hat einen sehr lebhaften Geist.

For the next example it wouldn't be clear, because the person could have a great mind or a great spirit. It's both very much in there. (I would say.)

> - Er ist eine geistreiche Person.

So, whenever you read or hear the word *Geist* keep in mind that it may refer to both *mind* and *spirit* and emphasize for yourself by context and of cause by your own like.

## The shift between the words in translation

This is how I would visualize it:

```
        Verstand | Geist 
understanding | mind | spirit
```

Answer (score 6):

The most striking equivalent is

> Geist

So the Latin *mens sana in corpore sano* translates to *gesunder Geist in einem gesunden Körper*.

In the context *What's on your mind* I would translate it with "Was hast du im Sinn?"

Comment: It's worth noting that ïn "What's on your mind" Geist is not a reasonable translation.

Comment: @Christian It's worth noting that you wouldn't even translate mind in that case ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answers given are ok, but I have the feeling there's still a word which hasn't been mentioned: *Bewusstsein*, literally "conciousness", as in the concious and unconcious mind (or the *Bewusstsein* und the *Unterbewusstsein* or the "Unbewusste*.) Note that you could also speak of the *unbewusste Geist* or suchlike, and the philosphical context makes clear that we are talking about states of mind (*Geisteszustände*), so *Geist* would be the correct translation for mind in this case, but the context will allow to translate "mind" to Bewusstsein in those cases.

The usage of the term mind in "mindfulness" also comes to mind. While it is usually translated to "Achtsamkeit" in German, the mind, i.e. the *Bewußtsein* is at the core of the concept.

Comment: Bei "keep in mind" heißt *mind* übrigens *Gedächtnis*. Das wurde auch vergessen.

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is is "im Sinn."

That doesn't literally mean "mind," more like "sense," but it has the sense of having a "cognizance" of something.

Comment: Aus den Augen...

Answer (score -2):

Many people will dislike what I want to say, but for me it's a fact: there is no German word that renders the precise meaning of the English Word "mind " or the Spanish "mente "in its basic sense. Yes, the dictionaries give us "Geist", but you must admit that a word whose most common meaning is ghost cannot be a perfect equivalent of "mind". For me it has always been a paradox that people like Kant and many other "Denker"  have had to resort to the G word. Of course I don't want to imply that the German language is somehow inferior to others because of this (das ist selbstverständlich!)

Comment: Das Problem ist doch nicht die präzise Bedeutung des Wortes, sondern seine Mehrdeutigkeit - das glatte Gegenteil von Präzision, also. Nicht, dass der engl. Sprache deshalb etwas fehlte, aber m.E. lässt sich jeder englische Satz, in dem "mind" vorkommt, sofern man den Kontext kennt, präzise übersetzen, außer vielleicht jenen, in denen mit der Mehrdeutigkeit gespielt wird.